# Where do Felix's adventures continue?

Tags: super-sales-on-super-heroes

I recently finished up the third book of William D. Arand's *Super Sales on Super Heroes* book, following Felix as he leverages what is officially thought to be a useless power to forge an empire named Legion, despite up position from governments, supervillains, superheroes, and gods. The third book ends with him driven to an alternate universe Yosemite run by his half-brother Vince, with two of his main allies in the wind. The book came out in 2018. Has Arand announced a sequel? Is it continuing in a different series like *Otherlife* by same author?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [the author's Patreon](https://www.patreon.com/WilliamDArand) (Jan 2021)

> Q. Is there an SSOSH 4 on the horizon?
>
> A. Eventually.

and March 2020

> There will eventually be a 4th book. But it isn't anytime soon.

---

At present they're working on at least two other sequel novels and while Super Sales may be on their long-term to do list they've described their writing from 2017 and 2018 as having left them "*in a rut*", so I wouldn't hold your breath.

Answer (score 1):

[The fourth book has been released](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09Z7T4D53) as of May 5, 2022.

> In a world full of super powers, Felix had a pretty crappy one.
>
> He has the ability to modify any item he owns. To upgrade anything.
>
> Sounds great on paper. Almost like a video game.
>
> Except that the amount of power it takes to actually change, modify, or upgrade anything worthwhile is beyond his abilities.
>
> At least, that was until Felix leveraged a once-in-a-lifetime opportunity to give himself a great deal of points.
>
> Investing in Super Heroes and Super Villains and owning them. Using them, Felix built up an empire.
>
> An organization by the name of Legion.
>
> It grew to heights that could stand toe-to-toe with governments, even at a military level.
>
> Surprisingly, not a whole lot changed despite becoming a mega-company CEO.
>
> Politicians were still corrupt. Banks still held onto your money. And criminals still committed crime.
>
> Governments still wanted to take everything from Felix and Legion.
>
> In the end, Legion had to back down. Retreat back to a new homeworld. Losing important people in the process.
>
> Kit Carrington and Lillian Lux sacrificed themselves to save him and were marooned on a hostile planet. Even as their home world fell into ruin, Felix fell back.
>
> He resolved himself to wait for a chance to get back into the fight after tending to his wounded organization.
>
> Now, the Overgod Runner has just appeared and offered him a second chance.
>
> To rebuild Legion and crush everyone in his way. If he could do that, and take over the government of the country he’s about to be dropped into, he’ll get Kit and Lily back.
>
> There was no way Felix would let go of this chance, nor could he even consider the possibility of failure.
>
> It’s time to get Kit and Lily back.
>
> Legion First.